# jQuery code not working with MVC3 site

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to highlight my elements and add a link with jquery.

My Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mvc3Demo.Products>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<h2>List</h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#productList li').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).css({ 'background': 'green', 'cursor': 'pointer' });
            },
            function () {
                $(this).css('background', '');
            }
        ).click(function () {
            window.location = 'Product/Edit/' + $(this).attr('productid');
        });
    });
</script>

<ul id="productList">
@foreach (Mvc3Demo.Products p in Model)
{
    <li productid="@p.ProductsID">
        @p.Name
        <!--@Html.ActionLink("Bearbeiten", "Edit", "Product", p, null)-->
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

The JQuery will be found so that couldn't be the error ( i proofed it with firebug)

Error:

No Error occurs in Firebug and no highlighting and no link

Please help

Comment: Try writing `$('#productList li')` in the console of Firebug. Does it return any elements?

Comment: Are you sure javascript is enabled on your browser :)

Comment: it was always enabled i testet in in chrome and firefox

Comment: Since everything works now all is good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have something in your Layout page that broke the jQuery functionality?
Try to unbind your page from the Layout and test it indipendently.
Or post your Layout page to let us see what could be wrong with it...

**Edited after seeing the Layout page:**

There's the error. you already have the jquery reference in the layout page. This cause the error. Simply delete the reference from you page leaving the one in the layout) and everything is going to work.
I created a littel project to test it.

PS: I still don't understand why 2 references to the same javascritp file cause the error :/

Comment: There's the error. you already have the jquery reference in the layout page. This cause the error. Simply delete the reference from you page leaving the one in the layout) and everything is going to work.
I created a littel project to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I've put the HTML which would be output from your example above [into a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8kdyT/2/). As you can see, it appears to work correctly.

Is the URL in your reference to jQuery correct?

Comment: Does MVC update `script` references automatically according to the URL they views get displayed at?  I know ASP.Net Forms doesn't do that.

Comment: It does if you use `Url.Content("~/path/to/jquery.js")`

Comment: the behaviour is strange. now i use the directlink to the jquery and it also don'T work

Answer (score 0):

try to type

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>`

instead of

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />`

Comment: in firebug i see that the script was found